# NAudio - Read and write a Wav file

Tags: c#, naudio

Before applying any sound modification (using the sample frames), I'm trying to simply read a Wav file, and write out an identical one using the contents:

```
using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(@"input.wav"))
{
      using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(@"output.wav", reader.WaveFormat))
      {
            while (true)
            {
                var frame = reader.ReadNextSampleFrame();
                if (frame == null)
                      break;
                writer.WriteSample(frame[0]);
            }
      }
}
```

I'd expect this to write an identical Wav file. But it actually writes a (surprisingly larger file) with a very different sound (as if it's been supressed).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are converting to floating point samples, and back to whatever the source format was, and paying no attention to the number of channels. To do what you want you should just use the Read method to read into a byte array and write the same data into the writer.